# Sub-users and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for authentication.

I'm using it for signup and the editing of their account. I need the ability to add "sub" users to each account. I can get it to work if I remove :registerable from the User Model, but by doing this it breaks edit_user_registration_path.

What I need todo is:

Allow new users to sign up.

Allow existing customers to add "Sub Users" to their account.

I think I need to use a self-referencing relationship to create the account owner.

Heres the code I have at the moment

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :location, :country, :job_title, :company
end
```

(If I remove :registerable I can create new users using User CRUD)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController  
  def new
    @user = User.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :action => :index }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :action => :new, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Users/new

```
<h2>Register User</h2>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
    <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Register" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a :has_many :belongs to relationship inside your User. something like

```
 class User
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'User'
  ...
 end
```

and in your controller add a reference to your parent user.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController  
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.parent_id = params[:parent_id] 
    respond_to do |format|
  end
end
```